# Deploying MVC 4 to Azure Web Site with SQL db

Tags: deployment, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-sql-database

I just deployed my first Azure Web Site form a ASP.NET MVC 4 internet application template.  The application worked well on my local computer.  I followed the tutorial found here to deploy the web site:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-site-with-sql-database/

After deploying the site I can go the the website home page, my home controller does not require authentication.  When I try to log in I am directed to an error page.

I modified my web.config file to get a custom error message and I receive this:

> There is already an object named 'UserProfile' in the database.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: There is already an object named 'UserProfile' in the database.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): There is already an object named 'UserProfile' in the database.]
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1753346
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5295154
>      System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +242
>      System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1682
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout) +280
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +405
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +160
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement) +125
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements) +113
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, XDocument targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto) +672
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration) +267
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId) +133
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) +455
>      System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +62
>      System.Data.Entity.<>c__DisplayClass2`1.b_*0(DbContext c) +70
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c*_DisplayClass8.b_*6() +19
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +60
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +181
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.b*_4(InternalContext c) +7
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +110
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +185
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() +73
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +28
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +52
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +15
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Find(Object[] keyValues) +23
>      EnergyToolbase.Controllers.AccountController.Login(LoginModel model, String returnUrl) +94
>      lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +147
>      System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
>      System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +182
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +28
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult *) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +58
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +225
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +225
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass2a.b_*20() +24
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass25.b_*22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +99
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()+9629708
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Can someone please point help me find the issue here.

Comment: I have the same problem, what did you do to clean up your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like **System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration** is throwing up. It sounds like you have entity framework set up to insert something into your database via migrations that is already there (in this case *userprofile*)

I'd say make sure you are deploying against the correct database. Then check if you have already created the objects you need in your database and troubleshoot your migrations accordingly (*or delete all the objects in your database and try again since it seems like you are expecting a clean database for this deployment.*)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. My issue was I extended the userprofile table with emailid, phone etc and I had it in my data context. When i created a migration for it, it created the migration for user profile table.
While the default memebership security code already creates user profiles, roles and other tables on application start, when it tried to run my migration (which means it tried to recreate the user profile table), it complained "There is already an object named 'UserProfile' in the database."

My solution was to remove the user profile table manually from the migration and then add the other columns that I needed explicitly via alter table query in sql sever.

Since my Data Model already was expecting those columns in the UserProfile table, it ran fine.
Hope this helps anyone else save time.